# Google cloud build: No space left on device

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-build

I have been using google's cloud build for building my artifacts/docker for my deployment. But I am suddenly getting the following error when submitting a build:

`Creating temporary tarball archive of 1103 file(s) totalling 99.5 MiB before compression.
ERROR: gcloud crashed (IOError): [Errno 28] No space left on device`

I have increased the diskSizeGB size as well but still I am getting this error. Where does cloud build happen in the cloud or which VM ? How to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Build is a service. While its builds are on GCE VMs these are VMs managed by the service and opaque to you. You cannot access the build service's resources directly.

What value did you try for `diskSizeGB`?

Please updating your question to include the (salient parts of) cloudbuild.yaml and the gcloud command that you're using to submit the job.

I'm wondering whether the error corresponds to a lack of space locally (your host) rather than on the service's VM.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Apparently the disk of the host machine was full.

Answer (score 0):

`diskSizeGb` seems to be only available in [Private Pools](https://cloud.google.com/build/pricing) of Cloud Build.  Couldn't find a way to increase disk size in normal cloud build.

Instructions for setting up Private Pool is [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/create-manage-private-pools).

Also the default disk size is 100GB as of March 2023.